# How to put a non-breaking space in an NSString?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsstring

I would like to define an `NSString`, of length 1, whose only character is a **non-breaking space**. How should I do ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use *universal character names*:

```
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space
NSString* const nonBreakingSpace = @"\u00A0";

// small-u takes four digits, big-u takes eight
// NSString* const nonBreakingSpace = @"\U000000A0";
```

Comment: Just a little side note here: if you’re sending this through localisation, for me only the uppercase U worked, but with 4 digits.